# HTML CSS (responsive drop down menu)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now. I need my navigation to be responsive. By responsive, i need my nav to still show its links when minimized and dragged to the very left. What my code does now is that the links disappear as if there is no nav bar at all when minimized. Thank you in advance!
[image: Normal view]

[image: Minimized view]

Normal view (which is also how i need my nav to look like when minimized)
Current minimized window

Here is my drop down menu code for our CSS:

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ffffff;/*bg color of drop down menu*/


}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;

    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999; /* home my acct etc */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#menu li:hover > a { /*font color of nav while hover */
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFE87C; /* blue */


}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #000000;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background:#FFE87C; /* bg color ng drop down yellow */
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;

}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/

}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
    color: black; /* font color of drop down */


}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color:  #EDDA74;/*hover of link blue*/
    color:#000000;

}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #D1D0CE;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #D1D0CE;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    /* nav-wrap */
    #menu-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu-wrap * {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* menu icon */
    #menu-trigger {
        display: block; /* show menu icon */
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;        
        padding: 0 0 0 35px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #111;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 10px center, linear-gradient(#444, #111);
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    }

    /* main nav */
    #menu {
        margin: 0; padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #48CCCD;
        display: none;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: -8px;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
    }   

    #menu ul {
        position: static;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
        box-shadow: none;               
    }

    #menu ul ul {
        margin: 0 0 0 20px !important;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu li {
        position: static;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        border: 0;
        margin: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;           
    }

    #menu ul li{
        margin-left: 20px;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu a{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
        color: #999;
    }

    #menu a:hover{
        color: #fafafa;
    }   

    #menu ul a{
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;        
    }

    #menu ul a:hover{
        background: none;   
    }

    #menu ul li:first-child a:after,
    #menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
        border: 0;
    }       

}
```

Comment: Well you have everything set to specification, instead you need to use % values. For instance you have width:800px in you #menu... Go back and change the values to percentage values to get desired responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set the "html, body" tags in your CSS with `min-width: x% / xpx`, x being your choice, e.g. `min-width: 700px` or `min-width: 75%`